# terraform: Overriding same variables in different tf files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 buckets A and B which requires lifecycle polices but ***different expiration days.***

Since they both are root modules in same directory they share common variables.tf file

Lifecycle policy code for both A and B

Note:- both the bucket code are in different file as both have different configurations

Bucket A file's code

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "A_log" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket # for B bucket aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket
  rule {
    id     = "expire current version after ${var.s3_expiration_days}, noncurrent version after ${var.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days} days"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = var.s3_expiration_days
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = var.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
}
```

B bucket's file code

```
 resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "B_log" {
      bucket = aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket 
      rule {
        id     = "expire current version after ${var.s3_expiration_days}, noncurrent version after ${var.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days} days"
        status = "Enabled"
        expiration {
          days = var.s3_expiration_days
        }
        noncurrent_version_expiration {
          noncurrent_days = var.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
        }
      }
    }
```

variables.tf

bucket A needs 30( current)  and 3 day ( non current versions) to expire, however B bucket needs 0 ( current)  and 90 ( non current versions) respectively.

How do I achieve this?

Note:- I do not want to hardcode value for any of the bucket.

```
variable "s3_expiration_days" {
  type        = number
  description = "S3 bucket objects expiration days https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#days"
  default     = 30
}

variable "s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days" {
  type        = number
  description = "S3 bucket noncurrent version objects expiration days https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#noncurrent_days"
  default     = 3
}
```

Comment: Are the bucket names per-defined as well, or just randomly generated by TF?

Comment: they are predefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest and most scalable way would be to do it through a single variable map:

```
variable "buckets_config" {
  default = {
    "bucket-name-a" = {
       s3_expiration_days = 30
       s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days = 3
    }
    "bucket-name-b" = {
       s3_expiration_days = 0
       s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days = 90
    }    
  }
}

# then

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = var.buckets_config
  bucket = each.key
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "A_log" {
  for_each = var.buckets_config
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket[each.key].bucket
  rule {
    id     = "expire current version after ${each.value.s3_expiration_days}, noncurrent version after ${each.value.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days} days"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = each.value.s3_expiration_days
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = each.value.s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
}
```

**UDPATE**

For two different buckets:

```
# for bucket A
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "A_log" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket 
  rule {
    id     = "expire current version after ${var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket].s3_expiration_days}, noncurrent version after ${var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket].s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days} days"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket].s3_expiration_days
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.A.bucket].s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
}


# for bucket B
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "A_log" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket 
  rule {
    id     = "expire current version after ${var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket].s3_expiration_days}, noncurrent version after ${var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket].s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days} days"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket].s3_expiration_days
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = var.buckets_config[aws_s3_bucket.B.bucket].s3_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear A bucket config and B bucket config are in the different file.
Your current code I think assumes single file.
I will update in my code

Comment: @JatinMehrotra If they are within same module, you can join them into a single file. That's how it should be anyway. Otherwise, you are just duplicating code.

Comment: I dont think so we are duplicating code, as I mentioned in my update that they are two separate file and both the buckets are very different from each other, which results in very different bucket configurations.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I updated the answer for two different buckets.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra How did it go? Still unclear how you can do it with separate files?

Comment: I am so sorry Marcin I couldn't give you an update, just handling another issue but definitely I will update it a day

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful answer. I really learned a lot from this answer. Much appreciated for time and efforts